# How to replace values in my array of objects using key from other object in another array

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays of objects

*NOTE: status and original-language can't be set manually as they change all the time, these are custom fields. The slugs from fields make up all custom fields.*

```
const items = [
  {
    name: 'Surviving the Game',
    status: 'ffdb29ba075fcbc0b71295c31a13d64f',
    original-language: 'b4ebbe06702794d1cf375274197267b2',
  },
  {
    name: 'Some Movie',
    status: 'cd53c082c6ca9e7d3ec66890e66c01f3',
    original-language: '7a1cac74217747933bb3915888dea090',
  },
];
const fields = [
  {
    slug: 'status',
    options: [
      {
        name: 'Released',
        id: 'ffdb29ba075fcbc0b71295c31a13d64f',
      },
      {
        name: 'Upcoming',
        id: 'cd53c082c6ca9e7d3ec66890e66c01f3',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    slug: 'original-language',
    options: [
      {
        name: 'de',
        id: 'b4ebbe06702794d1cf375274197267b2',
      },
      {
        name: 'en',
        id: '7a1cac74217747933bb3915888dea090',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

status and original-language in [items] have an id value which matches an option in the corresponding fields array.

I am trying to return a new array for [items] with the name from options with the matching id.

eg:

```
[
  {
    name: 'Surviving the Game',
    status: 'Released',
    original-language: 'de',
  },
  {
    name: 'Some Movie',
    status: 'Upcoming',
    original-language: 'en',
  },
];
```

How would I go about this with ES6/7?

I am not sure where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would accomplish this by creating a `lookup` object that houses lookups for both your statuses and languages. You can then use this lookup object when mapping through your `items`.

```js
var items = [
  {
    name: 'Surviving the Game',
    status: 'ffdb29ba075fcbc0b71295c31a13d64f',
    "original-language": 'b4ebbe06702794d1cf375274197267b2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Some Movie',
    status: 'cd53c082c6ca9e7d3ec66890e66c01f3',
    "original-language": '7a1cac74217747933bb3915888dea090'
  }
];

var fields = [
  {
    slug: 'status',
    options: [
      {
        name: 'Released',
        id: 'ffdb29ba075fcbc0b71295c31a13d64f'
      },
      {
        name: 'Upcoming',
        id: 'cd53c082c6ca9e7d3ec66890e66c01f3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    slug: 'original-language',
    options: [
      {
        name: 'de',
        id: 'b4ebbe06702794d1cf375274197267b2'
      },
      {
        name: 'en',
        id: '7a1cac74217747933bb3915888dea090'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const lookup = {};

fields.forEach(field => {
  lookup[field.slug] = field.options.reduce((all, option) => ({
    ...all,
    [option.id]: option.name
  }), {})
});

const translatedItems = items.map(item => {
  return Object.entries(item)
    .reduce((all, [key, val]) => ({
      ...all,
      [key]: lookup[key] ? lookup[key][val] : val
    }),{});
});

console.log(translatedItems);
```

Comment: Thanks.. so close. The issue is that status and original-language are not constant so  'translatedItems' needs to be dynamic not set manually. These keys will change all the time. The slugs in fields is the way to know what the keys in items will be. So if fields had another item slug: 'color', then each item would have a color key and value too.

Comment: Sure, the code has been updated to essentially look in our lookup for any key that may exist in our item object. If there is no lookup for it, the value from items is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

I'd define a function that obtains the value for a field, like so:

```
function valueForField(field, id) {
    const field = fields.find((itemfields) => itemfields.slug === field);
    if(!field) return null;
    const option = field.options.find(option => option.id === id);
    if(!option) return null;
    return option.name;
}
```

This can then be used like so:

```
const newItems = items.map(item => {
    const { name } = item;
    const newItem = {name};
    newItem["original-language"] = valueForField('original-language', item["original-language"]);
    newItem.status = valueForField('status', item.status);
    return newItem;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` to create a new array of objects having `name`, `status` and `originalLanguage` fields along with the `find` method to get the `name` from `fields` for every `status` identifier.

```js
const items = [{
    name: 'Surviving the Game',
    status: 'ffdb29ba075fcbc0b71295c31a13d64f',
    originalLanguage: 'b4ebbe06702794d1cf375274197267b2',
  },
  {
    name: 'Some Movie',
    status: 'cd53c082c6ca9e7d3ec66890e66c01f3',
    originalLanguage: '7a1cac74217747933bb3915888dea090',
  },
];
const fields = [{
      slug: 'status',
      options: [{
          name: 'Released',
          id: 'ffdb29ba075fcbc0b71295c31a13d64f',
        },
        {
          name: 'Upcoming',
          id: 'cd53c082c6ca9e7d3ec66890e66c01f3',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      slug: 'original-language',
      options: [{
          name: 'de',
          id: 'b4ebbe06702794d1cf375274197267b2',
        },
        {
          name: 'en',
          id: '7a1cac74217747933bb3915888dea090',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  newArr = items.map(i => ({
    name: i.name,
    status: fields.find(f => f.slug == 'status').options.find(o => o.id == i.status).name,
    originalLanguage: fields.find(f => f.slug == 'original-language').options.find(l => l.id == i.originalLanguage).name
  }));

console.log(newArr);
```